# How to address raw types and unchecked warnings?

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to implement a generic HashTable. In my code, I have nodes in the array. I'm trying to initialize the size of my array in my default constructor with my generic Node class. I'm trying to solve these warnings without `@SuppressWarnings`

I've already tried `table = (Node<K,V>[]) new Object[capacity];` but I'm receiving the same warning:

Here's what I have:

```
public class HashTable<K,V> implements Table<K,V>{

private static final int INIT_CAPACITY = 4;
private int n;
public int tableSize; 
public Node<K,V>[] table;

public HashTable(){
    this(INIT_CAPACITY);
}

public HashTable(int capacity){
    this.tableSize = capacity;
    this.n = 0;
    //table = (Node<K,V>[]) new Object[capacity]; // Also gives warnings
    table = (Node<K,V>[]) new Node[capacity]; // Warnings occur here
}
```

And my generic node class:
    public class Node{

```
public K nodeKey; // key
public V nodeValue; // value
Node<K,V> next;


public Node(){

}

public Node(K key, V value, Node<K,V> next){
    this.nodeKey = key;
    this.nodeValue = value;
    this.next = next;
}


public K getKey(){
    return nodeKey;
}

public V getValue(){
    return nodeValue;
}

}
```

Thanks!
Here's what I get when I compile:

`HashTable.java:17: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Node
        table = (Node<K,V>[]) new Node[capacity];
                                  ^
  missing type arguments for generic class Node<K,V>
  where K,V are type-variables:
    K extends Object declared in class Node
    V extends Object declared in class Node
HashTable.java:17: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
        table = (Node<K,V>[]) new Node[capacity];
                              ^
  required: Node<K,V>[]
  found:    Node[]
  where K,V are type-variables:
    K extends Object declared in class HashTable
    V extends Object declared in class HashTable
2 warnings`

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot.

Comment: That's unfortunate. One of the requirements states that there should be no warnings. Thanks for your feedback.